# Is there a book about the history of linear programming?

Tags: books, history

Is there any book about the history of linear programming? I would like to know more about the persons involved in the beginning of the field. I know about Kantorovich, Dantzig and Von Neumann, but I'm searching for a book that organizes the history in a chronological narrative and reports about the people involved but not as famous as the previous three.

Comment: I take it that you have already searched online for ***history of linear programming***? There are lots of articles.   A search on **Google Scholar**  also yields plenty of results. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=1%2C5&q=history+of+linear+programming&btnG=

Answer (score 9):

I suggest having a look at the following book:

[Grötschel, M. (Ed.). (2012). Optimization stories. Dt. Mathematiker-Vereinigung.](http://www.zib.de/groetschel/publications/OptimizationStories.pdf)

The book has a number of chapters and in particular a chapter titled "Linear Programming Stories" which can interest you.